# Moving an image of a TitleAreaDialog to the left

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm working on a SWT/Jface project based on Java SE, i want to move the image of a TitleAreaDialog to the left. is it possible ? if not is there anyway ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the layout data of the image label as follows:

```
    TitleAreaDialog tad = new TitleAreaDialog(getShell()) {

        @Override
        protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
            Control control = super.createContents(parent);
            Label label = getTitleImageLabel();
            FormData data = (FormData) label.getLayoutData();
            data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
            data.right = null;
            return control;
        }

    };
    tad.setTitle("title");
    tad.setTitleImage(Activator.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(
            Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "image.gif").createImage());
    tad.open();
```

Comment: You also need to take care of the attachments of other controls (depending on the dialog state) and the fact that the layout is reset in response to shell resize and some other events.

Comment: You're right, there's no good way of handling the resize/message change events.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to configure it using API, the layout is hard-coded. One way is to hack into the dialog controls and change their layout data, but it is likely easier to implement your own class (using `TitleAreaDialog` as an example).

If you subclass `TitleAreaDialog` you have to override `createContents(Composite)` method, otherwise the `TitleAreaDialog` will create its own title area by calling `createTitleArea()`. I suggest that at first you just copy the code from `TitleAreaDialog.createContents()` and start replacing stuff that you need to be done differently. I don't know exactly what needs to be done without actually doing everything.

Comment: Thank you, i extended the TitleAreaDialog but i have no idea how to do it. if it is possible can you put a piece of code ?

Comment: @GoodSpeed Unfortunately, this can't be done with a piece of code, you need several pieces and you'll only find out by trying.