# TitleAreaDialog - adjusting the title image

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface, titleareadialog

So I am creating a image to place in the title area.  Everything works with the exception that only a 1/4th of the image is displayed?

my image is actually text and a image combine in one image EX:  JKTeater [  ] <-- icon
so right now only JKT is showing in the title area

Here is the create() method

```
public void create() {
  super.create();
  setTitle("JKTeater Application");
  setMessage("Hello World");
  if (image != null) setTitleImage(image);

}
```

1. Is there a specific size that the title area code allows for?
2. Is there a way to place the end of the image at the end of the title area?
3. Can you use a layout to move it around?
4. How can I get a black horizonal line at the bottom of the title area?

***EDIT***

[image]

I am sure that it would be asking to much to see if you can actually change the background color from a basic color to a gradient

Comment: Ok, so your image is not completely shown? Can you upload the image as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example `TitleAreaDialog`. As you can see, the `Image` is completely shown and aligned to the right:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TitleAreaDialog dialog = new MyTitleAreaDialog(shell);
    dialog.setTitleAreaColor(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND).getRGB());
    dialog.open();
}

private static class MyTitleAreaDialog extends TitleAreaDialog
{
    private Image image;

    public MyTitleAreaDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
        image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), "/home/baz/Desktop/StackOverflow.png");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean close() {
        if (image != null)
            image.dispose();
        return super.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
        Control contents = super.createContents(parent);

        setTitle("Title");
        setMessage("Message");

        if (image != null)
            setTitleImage(image);

        return contents;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        // YOUR LINE HERE!
        Label line = new Label(parent, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        line.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, true));

        return composite;
    }
}
```

[image]

> Is there a specific size that the title area code allows for?

AFAIK there are no restrictions to the size. I tried using an `Image` that was larger than my screen resolution and it was fully displayed. The `Dialog` was obviously unusable though.

> I am sure that it would be asking to much to see if you can actually change the background color from a basic color to a gradient

The background color can be changed using `dialog.setTitleAreaColor(RGB)` (in this case the widget background color), but you cannot use a gradient. There is a deprecated method [`getTitleArea()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TitleAreaDialog.html#getTitleArea%28%29) which would return the title area `Composite`, but I really wouldn't recommend using that.

> How can I get a black horizonal line at the bottom of the title area?

The line at the bottom was achieved by using:

```
Label line = new Label(parent, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
line.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, true));
```

> Can you use a layout to move it around?

There is a similar question here:

[Moving an image of a TitleAreaDialog to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528399/moving-an-image-of-a-titleareadialog-to-the-left)

The answers there explain how to change details of the `TitleAreaDialog`. Maybe read up on them.

Comment: I will ask this here instead of opening another question.  The above was great!!  Can you change the font for setTitle("Hello");